# Which pagination is more efficient with MongoDB and Flask

Tags: pagination, flask, pymongo, mongoengine, mongoalchemy

I found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) a nice template for a pagination. However, this example is done with
SQLlite.

It seems that it is possible to do pagination with [flask-mongoengine](https://github.com/mechanicalchopsticks/MongoEngine-Pagination/blob/master/mongoenginepagination/__init__.py), 
[flask-mongoalchemy](https://github.com/cobrateam/flask-mongoalchemy/blob/master/examples/books_collection/collection/views.py)
and [pymongo](https://gist.github.com/illerucis/4586359).

I created a little code with PyMongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#mongod --dbpath /home/mic/databases/

def fill_data(users_no):
    for i in range(users_no):
        doc = {
            '_id': str(i),
            'uname': "name_" + str(i),
        }
        sDB.insert(doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = MongoClient().test
    sDB = db.users

    fill_data(10)

    users_no = sDB.find().count()
```

Which of three MongoDB drivers would work best and is most efficient for above Flask template?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple operation like that they're extremely likely to do the same underlying command. I can tell you that MongoAlchemy just does a call out to mongo as you would expect to get the count.